# simple way to download spring framework for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I am new comer for spring framework. I want to setup my first spring project on my eclipse(windows platform).

I try to search for jars for spring framework got the link as **spring.io** for download but it shows some instruction for setup the **maven** and **gradle**, which i donot know how to setup, I tried those links but those instruction is really hard to understand as of now
..

There is any other way to setup spring framework project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [Spring Tool Suite](https://spring.io/tools/sts) for Eclipse. In the Menubar select: Windows > Eclipse Marketplace.

Search for "Spring"

[image: Spring in the Eclipse Marketplace]

And select the version that suits your needs.

In order to start using this Spring-tooling from the Eclipse IDE, you can read the guide: [Getting Started: Working a Getting Started guide with STS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/)

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question, does it?

Comment: @Jmini... what next.. I downloaded the spring core jars. from the market.. while those jars are avalible in all the project of my workspace??

Comment: With the *Spring Tool Suite* installed, you are able for example to create a *New Spring Project* from Eclipse. It really depend on what you are building. Read the guides https://spring.io/guides/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a look to Maven or Gradle. Using one of these tools you will be able to declare the dependencies of your project (including spring modules) in a json or xml file.

[More info](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)